# Bash: What does ">|" do?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, pipe

I have just seen this written down;

```
$ some-command >| /tmp/output.txt
```

Vertical pipes are used in standard redirects "piping" the output of one command to another, is `>|` in fact completely useless as it would be the same as just `>` in this scenario?

Comment: Look for `>|` at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21/14195276#14195276

Comment: For the *rest* of the picture, I highly recommend [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/135943)

Answer (score 259, accepted):

It's not useless - it's a specialised form of the plain `>` redirect operator (and, perhaps confusingly, nothing to do with pipes). `bash` and most other modern shells have an option `noclobber`, which prevents redirection from overwriting or destroying a file that already exists. For example, if `noclobber` is true, and the file `/tmp/output.txt` already exists, then this should fail:

```
$ some-command > /tmp/output.txt
```

However, you can explicitly override the setting of `noclobber` with the `>|` redirection operator - the redirection will work, even if `noclobber` is set.

You can find out if `noclobber` is set in your current environment with `set -o`.

For the historical note, both the "noclobber" option and its bypass features come from `csh` (late 70s). `ksh` copied it (early 80s) but used `>|` instead of `>!`. POSIX specified the `ksh` syntax (so all POSIX shells including bash, newer ash derivatives used as sh on some systems support it). Zsh supports both syntaxes. I don't think it was added to any Bourne shell variant but I might be wrong.

Comment: @sch - re your historical note (thanks for the extra info, btw) - FreeBSD's `sh` has `noclobber`, since about May 2002.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear from the answer, `>|` is same as forced version of `>`: it doesn't mind how `noclobber` has been configured but will always overwrite any existing file if technically possible.