# What are the shell's control and redirection operators?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, control-flow

I often see tutorials online that connect various commands with different symbols. For example:

```
command1 |  command2
command1 &  command2
command1 || command2    
command1 && command2
```

Others seem to be connecting commands to files:

```
command1  > file1
command1  >> file1
```

What are these things? What are they called? What do they do? Are there more of them?

---

[Meta thread about this question.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3177/22222).

Answer (score 585, accepted):

These are called shell operators and yes, there are more of them. I will give a brief overview of the most common among the two major classes, [control operators](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_113) and [redirection operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), and how they work with respect to the bash shell.

### A. Control operators

[POSIX definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_113)

> In the shell command language, a token that performs a control function.
> It is one of the following symbols:

> ```
> &   &&   (   )   ;   ;;   <newline>   |   ||
> ```

And `|&` in bash.

A `!` is **not** a control operator but a [Reserved Word](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04). It becomes a logical NOT [negation operator] inside [Arithmetic Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_02) and inside test constructs (while still requiring an space delimiter).

#### A.1 List terminators

- `;` : Will run one command after another has finished, irrespective of the outcome of the first.

  ```
    command1 ; command2
  ```

First `command1` is run, in the foreground, and once it has finished, `command2` will be run.

A newline that isn't in a string literal or after certain keywords is *not* equivalent to the semicolon operator. A list of `;` delimited simple commands is still a *list* - as in the shell's parser must still continue to read in the simple commands that follow a `;` delimited simple command before executing, whereas a newline can delimit an entire command list - or list of lists. The difference is subtle, but complicated: given the shell has no previous imperative for reading in data following a newline, the newline marks a point where the shell can begin to evaluate the simple commands it has already read in, whereas a `;` semi-colon does not.

- `&` : This will run a command in the background, allowing you to continue working in the same shell.

  ```
     command1 & command2
  ```

Here, `command1` is launched in the background and `command2` starts running in the foreground immediately, without waiting for `command1` to exit.

A newline after `command1` is optional.

#### A.2 Logical operators

- `&&` : Used to build AND lists, it allows you to run one command only if another exited successfully.

  ```
     command1 && command2
  ```

Here, `command2` will run after `command1` has finished and *only* if `command1` was successful (if its exit code was 0). Both commands are run in the foreground.

This command can also be written

```
    if command1
    then command2
    else false
    fi
```

or simply `if command1; then command2; fi` if the return status is ignored.

- `||` : Used to build OR lists, it allows you to run one command only if another exited unsuccessfully.

  ```
     command1 || command2
  ```

Here, `command2` will only run if `command1` failed (if it returned an exit status other than 0). Both commands are run in the foreground.

This command can also be written

```
    if command1
    then true
    else command2
    fi
```

or in a shorter way `if ! command1; then command2; fi`.

Note that `&&` and `||` are left-associative; see [Precedence of the shell logical operators &&, ||](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators) for more information.

- `!`: This is a reserved word which acts as the “not” operator (but must have a delimiter), used to negate the return status of a command — return 0 if the command returns a nonzero status, return 1 if it returns the status 0. Also a logical NOT for the `test` utility.

  ```
    ! command1

    [ ! a = a ]
  ```

And a true NOT operator inside Arithmetic Expressions:

```
    $ echo $((!0)) $((!23))
    1 0
```

#### A.3 Pipe operator

- `|` : The pipe operator, it passes the output of one command as input to another. A command built from the pipe operator is called a [pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)).

  ```
     command1 | command2
  ```

  Any output printed by `command1` is passed as input to `command2`.
- `|&` : This is a shorthand for `2>&1 |` in bash and zsh. It passes both standard output and standard error of one command as input to another.

  ```
    command1 |& command2
  ```

#### A.4 Other list punctuation

`;;` is used solely to mark the end of a [case statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs). Ksh, bash and zsh also support `;&` to fall through to the next case and `;;&` (not in ATT ksh) to go on and test subsequent cases.

`(` and `)` are used to [group commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) and launch them in a subshell. `{` and `}` also group commands, but do not launch them in a subshell. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270440/simple-logical-operators-in-bash/6270803#6270803) for a discussion of the various types of parentheses, brackets and braces in shell syntax.

### B. Redirection Operators

[POSIX definition of Redirection Operator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_318)

> In the shell command language, a token that performs a redirection function. It is one of the following symbols:

> ```
> <     >     >|     <<     >>     <&     >&     <<-     <>
> ```

These allow you to control the input and output of your commands. They can appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command. Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.

- `<` : Gives input to a command.

  ```
    command < file.txt
  ```

The above will execute `command` on the contents of `file.txt`.

- `<>` : same as above, but the file is open in *read+write* mode instead of *read-only*:

  ```
    command <> file.txt
  ```

If the file doesn't exist, it will be created.

That operator is rarely used because commands generally only *read* from their stdin, though [it can come handy in a number of specific situations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164449).

- `>` : Directs the output of a command into a file.

  ```
    command > out.txt
  ```

The above will save the output of `command` as `out.txt`. If the file exists, its contents will be overwritten and if it does not exist it will be created.

This operator is also often used to choose whether something should be printed to [standard error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) or [standard output](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29):

```
    command >out.txt 2>error.txt
```

In the example above, `>` will redirect standard output and `2>` redirects standard error. Output can also be redirected using `1>` but, since this is the default, the `1` is usually omitted and it's written simply as `>`.

So, to run `command` on `file.txt` and save its output in `out.txt` and any error messages in `error.txt` you would run:

```
    command < file.txt > out.txt 2> error.txt
```

- `>|` : Does the same as `>`, but will overwrite the target, even if the shell has been configured to refuse overwriting (with `set -C` or `set -o noclobber`).

  ```
    command >| out.txt
  ```

If `out.txt` exists, the output of `command` will replace its content. If it does not exist it will be created.

- `>>` : Does the same as `>`, except that if the target file exists, the new data are appended.

  ```
    command >> out.txt
  ```

If `out.txt` exists, the output of `command` will be appended to it, after whatever is already in it. If it does not exist it will be created.

- `>&` : (per POSIX spec) when surrounded by **digits** (`1>&2`) or `-` on the right side (`1>&-`) either redirects only **one** file descriptor or closes it (`>&-`).

A `>&` followed by a file descriptor number is a portable way to redirect a file descriptor, and `>&-` is a portable way to close a file descriptor.

If the right side of this redirection is a file please read the next entry.

- `>&`, `&>`, `>>&` and `&>>` : (read above also) Redirect both standard error and standard output, replacing or appending, respectively.

  ```
    command &> out.txt
  ```

Both standard error and standard output of `command` will be saved in `out.txt`, overwriting its contents or creating it if it doesn't exist.

```
    command &>> out.txt
```

As above, except that if `out.txt` exists, the output and error of `command` will be appended to it.

The `&>` variant originates in `bash`, while the `>&` variant comes from csh (decades earlier). They both conflict with other POSIX shell operators and should not be used in portable `sh` scripts.

- `<<` : A here document. It is often used to print multi-line strings.

  ```
     command << WORD
         Text
     WORD
  ```

  Here, `command` will take everything until it finds the next occurrence of `WORD`, `Text` in the example above, as input .  While `WORD` is often `EoF` or variations thereof, it can be any alphanumeric (and not only) string you like. When any part of `WORD` is quoted or escaped, the text in the here document is treated literally and no expansions are performed (on variables for example). If it is unquoted, variables will be expanded. For more details, see the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents).

  If you want to pipe the output of `command << WORD ... WORD` directly into another command or commands, you have to put the pipe on the same line as `<< WORD`, you can't put it after the terminating WORD or on the line following.  For example:

  ```
     command << WORD | command2 | command3...
         Text
     WORD
  ```
- `<<<` : Here strings, similar to here documents, but intended for a single line. These exist only in the Unix port or rc (where it originated), zsh, some implementations of ksh, yash and bash.

  ```
    command <<< WORD
  ```

Whatever is given as `WORD` is expanded and its value is passed as input to `command`. This is often used to pass the content of variables as input to a command. For example:

```
     $ foo="bar"
     $ sed 's/a/A/' <<< "$foo"
     bAr
     # as a short-cut for the standard:
     $ printf '%s\n' "$foo" | sed 's/a/A/'
     bAr
     # or
     sed 's/a/A/' << EOF
     $foo
     EOF
```

A few other operators (`>&-`, `x>&y` `x<&y`) can be used to close or duplicate file descriptors. For details on them, please see the relevant section of your shell's manual ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Moving-File-Descriptors) for instance for bash).

That only covers the most common operators of Bourne-like shells. Some shells have a few additional redirection operators of their own.

Ksh, bash and zsh also have constructs `<(…)`, `>(…)` and `=(…)` (that latter one in `zsh` only). These are not redirections, but [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution).

Comment: It would probably be worthwhile noting that not all shells are equal, and specifically highlighting the bash-specific features.

Comment: @GregHewgill yeah, I weaseled out of it by saying that I am discussing with respect to `bash`. This is being groomed as a canonical Q&A to close the various "What does this weird thingy do" questions and most of them are from users of bash. I'm hoping someone else will pitch in and answer for non bash shells, but highlighting the bash-specific ones makes a lot of sense. I'll have to check though, I don't know which they are off the top of my head.

Comment: `&>`, `>>>`, and `<<<` are all non-posix as is the reference to *not-only* non-alphanum chars in a here-doc's name. This answer also discusses very little about *how* they work - for example, it is almost worse than useless to talk about a *simple command* and a *command* without explaining what these are and how the shell decides.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks. They work on bash and zsh though. I don't know what, if anything, is truly bash-specific in that list. I should go through this and add the shells each works in but that would involve finding out first.

Comment: And ksh93, yash, mksh, and many others. But they will all likely operate slightly differently in edge-cases between shells - thats why these types of things are iffy.

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159268/44370) may help with the comparative angle.

Comment: @mikeserv >>> ? what does that do? where can I find out more about it? I know that you are not talking about >> which is standard.

Comment: @hildred - I dunno. Maybe I was just trying to be thorough...? More likely it was a typo. Sorry to disappoint...

Comment: The `&&` and `||` uses seem counterintuitive. Doesn't this mean that exit code 0 evaluates to `True` and non-zero evaluates to `False`?

Comment: @Arc676 No, they don't evaluate to true or false, that's a completely different context. This just means that an exit value of non-0 indicates a problem (not `false`) and an exit code of 0 indicates success (not `true`). That's always been the way and is quite standard. A non-0 exit code indicates an error in every environment I know of.

Comment: It should be noted that these symbols lose their special meaning and become ordinary textual characters when they are quoted (with `'`…`'` or `"`…`"`) or escaped (with ``\``); e.g., ``echo 'Tom & Jerry'`` or `grep \< prog.c`. Bash, specifically, also supports a `$'`…`'` syntax. These quoting methods — `'`…`'` and `"`…`"` (and `$'`…`'`) — differ in ways that are discussed elsewhere.

Comment: There's also the `>!` analogue of `>|` to be aware of, in some non-bash shells.

Comment: Can this excellent answer be edited to clarify one small aspect of redirects: Is there actually any difference between `cmd1 | cmd2` and `cmd2 < $( cmd1 )`? Why are there two ways, syntactically, to direct stdin from one process to another, and when do shell scripts tend to use one or the other? Are there any commonly-encountered limitations in other usual syntax + operators one can use, or any common confusions, caused by the "<" appearing _after_ the command it's directing into?

Comment: So `command < file.txt` is the same as `cat file.txt | command`?

Comment: @felwithe essentially, yes. In fact, you very rarely (if ever) need `cat file | command`, this is a classic example of [UUoC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) (useless use of cat).

Comment: When you're using `&`, you should be aware that `ctrl + c` only stops last command, other commands run in the background and you've to manually find and `kill` the processes.

Answer (score 93):

### Warning regarding ‘>’

Unix beginners who have just learned about I/O redirection (`<` and `>`)
often try things like

```
command … input_file > the_same_file
```

or

```
command … < file     > the_same_file
```

or, almost equivalently,

```
cat file | command … > the_same_file
```

(`grep`, `sed`, `cut`, `sort`, and `spell` are examples of commands
that people are tempted to use in constructs like these.) 
Users are surprised to discover that these scenarios result in the file becoming empty.

A nuance that doesn’t seem to be mentioned in the other answer can be found lurking
in the first sentence of the **Redirection** section of [bash(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be *redirected*
>   using a special notation interpreted by the shell.

The first five words should be bold, italic, underlined, enlarged, blinking,
colored red, and marked with a [image: exclamation mark in red triangle] icon,
to emphasize the fact that the shell performs the requested redirection(s)
*before the command is executed*. 
And remember also

> Redirection of output causes the file … to be opened for writing …. 
>   If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.

1. So, in this example:

   ```
   sort roster > roster
   ```

   the shell opens the `roster` file for writing, truncating it
   (i.e., discarding all its contents), before the `sort` program starts running. 
   Naturally, nothing can be done to recover the data.
2. One might naïvely expect that

   ```
   tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" < poem > poem
   ```

   might be better. 
   Because the shell handles redirections from left to right,
   it opens `poem` for reading (for `tr`’s standard input)
   before it opens it for writing (for standard output). 
   But it doesn’t help. 
   Even though this sequence of operations yields two file handles,
   they both point to the same file. 
   When the shell opens the file for reading, the contents are still there,
   but they still get clobbered before the program is executed.

#### So, what to do about it?

Solutions include:

- Check whether the program you’re running
  has its own, internal, capability to specify where the output goes. 
  This is often indicated by a `-o` (or `--output=`) token. 
  In particular,

  ```
  sort -o roster roster
  ```

  is roughly equivalent to

  ```
  sort roster > roster
  ```

  except, in the first case, the `sort` program opens the output file. 
  And it’s smart enough not to open the output file
  until *after* it has read all of the input file(s).

  Similarly, at least some versions of `sed` have a `-i` (edit **i**n place) option
  that can be used to write the output back out to the input file
  (again, *after* all the input have been read). 
  Editors like `ed`/`ex`, `emacs`, `pico`, and `vi`/`vim`
  allow the user to edit a text file and save the edited text in the original file. 
  Note that `ed` (at least) can be used non-interactively.

  - `vi` has a related feature. 
    If you type `:%!command`<kbd>Enter</kbd>,
    it will write the contents of the edit buffer out to *`command`*, read the output,
    and insert it into the buffer (replacing the original contents).
- Simple but effective:

  ```
  command … input_file > temp_file  &&  mv temp_file input_file
  ```

  This has the drawback that, if *`input_file`* is a link,
  it will (probably) be replaced by a separate file. 
  Also, the new file will be owned by you, with default protections. 
  In particular, this carries the risk that the file will be end up being world-readable,
  even if the original *`input_file`* wasn’t.

  Variations:

  - `command … input_file > temp_file  &&  cp temp_file input_file  &&  rm temp_file`
    which will still (potentially) leave the *`temp_file`* world-readable. 
    Even better:
  - `cp input_file temp_file  &&  command … temp_file > input_file  &&  rm temp_file`
    These preserve the link status, owner, and mode (protection) of the file,
    potentially at the cost of twice as much I/O. 
    (You may need to use an option like `-a` or `-p` on `cp`
    to tell it to preserve attributes.)
  - `command … input_file > temp_file  &&`
    `cp --attributes-only --preserve=all input_file temp_file  &&`
    `mv temp_file input_file`
    (broken into separate lines only for readability) 
    This preserves the mode of the file (and, if you’re root, the owner),
    but makes it owned by you (if you’re not root), and makes it a new, separate file.
- [This blog](http://backreference.org/2011/01/29/in-place-editing-of-files)
  (“In-place” editing of files) suggests and explains

  ```
  { rm input_file  &&  command … > input_file; } < input_file
  ```

  This requires that the *`command`* be able to process standard input
  (but almost all filters can). 
  The blog itself calls this a risky kludge and discourages its use. 
  And this will also create a new, separate file (not linked to anything),
  owned by you and with default permissions.
- The moreutils package has a command called `sponge`:

  ```
  command … input_file | sponge the_same_file
  ```

  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110545/23408) for more information.

Here’s something that came as a complete surprise to me:
[syntaxerror says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place#comment282614_11072):

> [Most of these solutions] will fail on a read-only file system,
>   where “read-only” means that your `$HOME` *will* be writable,
>   but `/tmp` will be **read-only** (by default). 
>   For instance, if you have Ubuntu, and you’ve booted into the Recovery Console,
>   this is commonly the case. 
>   Also, the here-document operator `<<<` will not work there either,
>   as it requires `/tmp` to be **read/write**
>   because it will write a temporary file into there as well.
>   (cf. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98606/bash-some-issue-when-using-read-variable-on-a-read-only-root-partition) includes an `strace`’d output)

The following may work in that case:

- **For advanced users only:**
  If your command is guaranteed to produce the same amount of output data
  as there is input (e.g., `sort`, or `tr` *without* the `-d` or `-s` option),
  you can try

  ```
  command … input_file | dd of=the_same_file conv=notrunc
  ```

  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11074/23408)
  and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11114/23408) for more information,
  including an explanation of the above, and alternatives that work
  if your command is guaranteed to produce the same amount of output data
  as there is input ***or less*** (e.g., `grep`, or `cut`). 
  These answers have the advantage that they do not require any free space
  (or they require very little). 
  The answers above of the form
  `command … input_file > temp_file && …`
  clearly require that there be enough free space for the system to be able
  to hold the entire input (old) file and output (new) file simultaneously;
  this is non-obviously true for most of the other solutions
  (e.g., `sed -i` and `sponge`) as well. 
  Exception: `sort … | dd …` will probably require lots of free space,
  because `sort` needs to read all of its input before it can write any output,
  and it probably buffers most if not all of that data in a temporary file.
- **For advanced users only:**

  ```
  command … input_file 1<> the_same_file
  ```

  may be equivalent to the `dd` answer, above. 
  The `n<> file` syntax opens the named file
  on file descriptor *`n`* *for both input and output*, without truncating it –
  sort of a combination of `n<`
  and `n>`. 
  Note: Some programs (e.g., `cat` and `grep`) may refuse to run in this scenario
  because they can detect that the input and the output are the same file. 
  See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11322/23408)
  for a discussion of the above,
  and a script that makes this answer work if your command is guaranteed
  to produce the same amount of output data as there is input ***or less***.
  Warning: I haven’t tested Peter’s script, so I don’t vouch for it.

#### So, what was the question?

This has been a popular topic on U&L; it is addressed in the following questions:

- [Is there a way to modify a file in-place?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11067/23408)
- [How can I make `iconv` replace the input file with the converted output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10241/23408)
- [Why does the command `shuf file > file` leave an empty file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110490/23408)
- [Can I read and write to the same file in Linux without overwriting it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36261/23408)
- [Redirect to the same file as the source file processed by the command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165989/23408)
- [Why does this `sort` command give me an empty file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/97446/23408)
- [Redirecting `tr` stdout to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48725/23408)
- [grep: input file 'X' is also the output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164236/23408)
- [Do redirection operators open file descriptors in parallel?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79036/23408)
- [Redirection not overwriting file but just producing a blank one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185596/23408)

… and that’s not counting Super User or Ask Ubuntu. 
I have incorporated a lot of the information from the answers to the above questions
here in this answer, but not all. 
(I.e., for more information, read the above-listed questions and their answers.)

<sup>P.S. I have **no** affiliation with the blog that I cited, above.</sup>

Comment: Since this question keeps on coming up, I thought I’d try my hand at writing a “canonical answer”. Should I post it here (and maybe link to it from some of the other more heavily trafficked questions), or should I move it to one of the questions that actually raises this issue? Also, is this perhaps a situation where questions should be merged?

Comment: [***/tmp***](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html#tag_10_01) 
*A directory made available for applications that need a place to create temporary files. Applications shall be allowed to create files in this directory, but shall not assume that such files are preserved between invocations of the application.*

Comment: @mikeserv: Yeah, (1) I'm quoting syntaxerror, and (2) I said I was surprised. I thought that, if anything would be read-write, it would be `/tmp`.

Comment: Well, the thing @syntaxerror said is doubly strange because, as I think, `dash` would be the default recovery shell on Ubuntu and it not only does not understand a `<<<` herestring, but it also gets anonymous pipes for `<<` heredocuments and doesn't mess with `${TMPDIR:-/tmp}` for that purpose at all. See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184711/52934) or [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182843/52934) for demos on here-document handling. Also why the *same amount of output **or less*** warning?

Comment: @mikeserv: Well, the `dd … conv=notrunc` and the `1<>` answers never truncate the output file, so, if the output of the command is less than the input (e.g., `grep`), there will be some bytes of the original left over at the end of the file. And, if the output is larger than the input (e.g., `cat -n`, `nl`, or (potentially) `grep -n`), there's a risk of overwriting old data before you've read it.

Comment: Well, because most commands will buffer anyway, you run that risk regardless, or, if not that, then a neverending loop of reading the output as it is written. The `dd conv=notrunc` is more risky where the pipe is concerned - it isn't reading the input file, but the pipe, and, in that scenario, not even common *input file is same as output file* safeguards will prohibit the loop mentioned. In general, unless you are completely certain of how a filesystem and a command's i/o lib will behave together, you can never safely overwrite a file in place without first assuring your own buffer.

Comment: I don't understand. If a program is buffering reads, then, at any given time, it has probably read more data than it has processed; i.e., the read pointer (at the kernel level) is leading the read pointer at the `stdio` level, where the processing is occurring. And, conversely, it has written less data than it has processed; i.e., the kernel-level write pointer is trailing the `stdio` write pointer. Therefore, unless you're doing something that bloats the data (e.g., `cat -n`), the write pointer will always lag behind the read pointer.

Comment: Commands also buffer writes, and sometimes do so by line rather than by byte count *(though admittedly, usually only when stdout is a tty - but that is not always the case)*. In those cases, given variable line lengths, the buffers could overrun one another. It's just not a safe way to approach writing to a file - not without *(at least)* an intermediate ring-buffer and/or guaranteed safe blocking factor of some kind. And there's the race involved between the shell's opening `1<>` and the command's opening the named file. In one of the links I used deleted/here-doc files as ring-buffers.

Comment: In the same vein as the dd, and probably not handling as many caveats, but conceptually simpler - `cat a | wc | tee a`.

Comment: @Manav: I don’t understand what you’re saying — how is your command “in the same vein as the dd”? — and I wonder how well you understand my answer.  But I see now that my answer was incomplete — it doesn’t mention that some commands that attempt to work around the problem will work *sometimes,* at random.  Your command is an example of that — it will work sometimes, but not always.

Comment: Is this true also on copy on write file systems like zfs? (Asking just for completeness sake)

Answer (score 37):

### More observations on `;`, `&`, `(` and `)`

- Note that some of the commands in terdon’s answer may be null. 
  For example, you can say

  ```
  command1 ;
  ```

  (with no `command2`).  This is equivalent to

  ```
  command1
  ```

  (i.e., it simply runs `command1` in the foreground and waits for it to complete. 
  Comparably,

  ```
  command1 &
  ```

  (with no `command2`) will launch `command1` in the background
  and then issue another shell prompt immediately.
- By contrast, `command1 &&`, `command1 ||`, and `command1 |` don’t make any sense. 
  If you type one of these,
  the shell will (probably) assume that the command is continued onto another line. 
  It will display the secondary (continuation) shell prompt,
  which is normally set to `>`, and keep on reading. 
  In a shell script, it will just read the next line
  and append it to what it has already read. 
  (Beware: this might not be what you want to happen.)

  Note: some versions of some shells may treat such incomplete commands as errors. 
  In such cases (or, in fact, in *any* case where you have a long command),
  you can put a backslash (`\`) at the end of a line
  to tell the shell to continue reading the command on another line:

  ```
  command1  &&  \
  command2
  ```

  or

  ```
  find starting-directory -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 5 -iname "*.some_extension" -type f \
                          -newer some_existing_file -user fred -readable -print
  ```
- As terdon says, `(` and `)` can be used to group commands. 
  The statement that they are “not really relevant” to that discussion is debatable. 
  Some of the commands in terdon’s answer may be command *groups*. 
  For example,

  ```
  ( command1 ; command2 )  &&  ( command3; command4 )
  ```

  does this:

  - Run `command1` and wait for it to finish.
  - Then, regardless of the result of running that first command,
    run `command2` and wait for it to finish.
  - Then, if `command2` succeeded,

    - Run `command3` and wait for it to finish.
    - Then, regardless of the result of running that command,
      run `command4` and wait for it to finish.

    If `command2` failed, stop processing the command line.
- Outside parentheses, `|` binds very tightly, so

  ```
  command1 | command2 || command3
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```
  ( command1 | command2 )  ||  command3
  ```

  and `&&` and `||` bind tighter than `;`, so

  ```
  command1 && command2 ; command3
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```
  ( command1 && command2 ) ;  command3
  ```

  i.e., `command3` will be executed regardless of the exit status
  of `command1` and/or `command2`.

Comment: Perfect, +1! I said they were not relevant because I did not want to go into that much detail. I wanted an answer that could work as a quick cheatsheet for newbies who're wondering what all the weird squiggles at the end of the various commands are. I did not mean to imply they're not useful. Thanks for adding all this.

Comment: I'm concerned about the "critical mass" problem -- if we post *everything* that we could possibly say about shells, we'll end up with our own **TL;DR** version of the Bash Reference Manual.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: Unlike in languages of the C family, `;` by itself (or without a command preceding it) is a syntax error, and not an empty statement. Thus `; ;` is an error. (A common pitfall for new users, IMHO). Also: `;;` is a special delimiter, for `case` statements.

Comment: @G-Man exactly, which is why I tried to keep mine more specific. The idea is to have a general Q&A against which we can close things like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/100704/22222) or [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136505/22222) as duplicates.

Comment: @muru: Good point, but let's generalize it. ***Any*** of the control operators that can appear between commands: `;`, `&&`, `||`, `&`, and `|`, are errors if they appear with nothing preceding them. Also, terdon addressed `;;` (briefly) in his answer.

Comment: @G-Man, is there any POSIX-compliant shell (or even commonly used shell) you can point to that will reject a line that ends in a non-escaped newline after `&&` (providing that the next line is a valid command)?  I've never seen that behavior (a shell failing on that) and [according to Gilles](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/253520/135943) such constructs are standard POSIX grammar....

Comment: @Wildcard: I'm obviously not understanding you.  It seems like you're asking whether I know of any POSIX-compliant shell that rejects standard POSIX grammar, and that would be an oxymoron.

Comment: @G-Man, well, your answer includes the sentence *"Note: some versions of some shells may treat such incomplete commands as errors."* So my question is, *which* versions of *what* shells?  (Because, as I linked above, I thought that all POSIX shells will accept such.)

Comment: @Wildcard: OK, I see where you're coming from.  The key word is "may"; all I was saying was that I don't guarantee that all shells will accept such constructs (i.e., YMMV).  Obviously I wrote that before I knew about the use of the `linebreak` token in the POSIX shell grammar.  So perhaps it's safe to say that all POSIX-compliant shells will accept them.  I stand by my statement as a general disclaimer; if you find an old enough pre-POSIX shell, such as an actual Bourne shell or older, all bets are off.

Comment: Further, you might consider the following point to be off-topic, since this page is focused on bash.  But a lot of the information here applies to a wide variety of shells, including exotic ones.  The C shell (which was very popular in the 1980s, as it was the first shell to offer command history) recognizes `|`, `&&`, and `||`, but it does not recognize them at the ends of lines (at least not `tcsh` version 6.18.01, dated 2012-02-14, which comes with Cygwin) — it gives the error `Invalid null command.`

Comment: Admittedly nitpicking, but curly braces would probably be a better choice when it comes to explaining command grouping because of the effects grouped commands may have on the current shell: compare e.g. `true && foo=bar : ; echo "$foo"` with `( true && foo=bar : ) ; echo "$foo"` and `{ true && foo=bar : ; } ; echo "$foo"` in dash, ksh93, or Bash/zsh in POSIX mode.

Comment: ...but now I see that the question had the [tag:bash] tag, making any point about special builtins less relevant. It still makes sense if we allow `command` to be a compound one.